# Isomorphism on spanned lattice

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, group-isomorphism

Let $\mathbf x=\left( \begin{matrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \end{matrix} \right)$ and $\mathbf y=\left( \begin{matrix}y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \end{matrix} \right)$ be two linearly independent vectors is $\mathbb R^2$ and let $K = \left[ \begin{matrix} x_1 & y_1 \\ x_2 & y_2 \end{matrix} \right] $. Let $W = \{a\mathbf x + b\mathbf  y|a,b \in \mathbb Z \}$

(a) Show that $\mathbb R^2 / W$ is isomorphic $(\mathbb R/\mathbb Z) * (\mathbb R/\mathbb Z) $

(b) If $\mathbf u, \mathbf v$ are two other linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^2$, with lattice $A$ and matrix $B$, show that $W = A$ if and only if $B = GK$ for some $2 * 2$ matrix $G$ with integral entries, and its determinant is $1$ or $-1$.

I’m not sure how I can start with this question. I know that $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ is isomorphic to the circle group but will that be able to help me?

For (b), I’m not sure how the hint that the matrix has integral entries and has determinant 1 or -1 will come into effect.

Would appreciate some hints to help me complete this question!

Comment: Possibly you want $B = KG$ if you're going to write $\bf x$ and $\bf y$ as the columns of $K$ but I'm too tired to figure this out right now.

Comment: Thanks I’ll try to look into that

Answer (score 1):

For (a) look at it like this

$$ (a, b) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \longleftrightarrow a{\bf x} + b{\bf y} $$
$$ (a, b) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \longleftrightarrow a{\bf x} + b{\bf y} $$

For (b) if you have a second basis ${\bf x}', {\bf y}'$ for $W$ then what can you say about the transformation

$$ T : W \to W$$

defined by $T({\bf x}) = {\bf x'}$ and $T({\bf y}) = {\bf y}'$? What does the matrix form of $T$ look like? (You will need to write ${\bf x'} = a{\bf x} + b{\bf y}$ and ${\bf y}' = c{\bf x} + d{\bf y}$.) What about $T^{-1}$?